# How to navigate through rows/columns of buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

This is probably a trivial question, however, i have yet to find an answer. I'm trying to improve my winforms application by adding the possibility of key navigation (arrow keys). The problem is I have a number of buttons arranged in rows and columns and it has proven troublesome to navigate. The UP/RIGHT and DOWN/LEFT arrows only increment and decrement the index rather than move in the specified direction. So far my only idea was to map the button indexes to a 2d array and use that as reference to the buttons, however, i have been unsuccessful. Anyone have some ideas or suggestions on how i could implement this?
I'm using C# on Visual studio 2008 and .NET3.5

```
Control[,] MyButtons = new Control[4,3] { {b1,b2,b3},{b4,b5,b6},{b7,b8,b9},{btn_Clear,b0,btn_Cancel}};
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
        switch (e.KeyValue)
        {
          case 13: //return
            { e.Handled = false; break; }

          case 39:  //Right
            {
               j++;
               break;
            }
          case 38:  //Up
            {
               i++;
               break;
            }
          case 37: //Left
            {
               j--;
               break;
            }

          case 40: //Down
            {
               i--;
               break;
            }
        }
        if (e.KeyValue != 13)
        {
           e.Handled = true;                         //Don't pass on the keystroke
           MyButtons[i,j].Focus(); // Set the focus to the selected control
          Application.DoEvents();
        }
}
```

With this code i keep getting this error for each element of the array
     Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'

Comment: Describe how things are laid out.  Directly on the form?  Inside a container such as a `TableLayoutPanel`?  Navigate...do you mean "change focus" to a different button when an arrow is pressed?  What have you tried...show some code.

Comment: The buttons are directly on the form, arrange in a 3x3 format. Basically what i'm asking for is a way to change focus to the button the arrow key is pointing towards, not the next one in the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a full example and you can extrapolate to your project/code.

The form itself:

[image]

Here's that form's code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmButtons : Form
    {
        private Int32 _selectedButton = 1;
        private Dictionary<Int32, Button> _buttonDict = new Dictionary<Int32, Button>();

        public frmButtons()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Tag != null))
            {
                Int32 i;
                if (Int32.TryParse(b.Tag.ToString(), out i))
                    _buttonDict.Add(i, b);
            }
            if (_buttonDict.Count > 0)
                _buttonDict[_selectedButton].Focus();
        }

        private void frmButtons_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                    _selectedButton -= 3;
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    _selectedButton += 3;
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    _selectedButton -= 1;
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
                case Keys.Right:
                    _selectedButton += 1;
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
                case Keys.Enter:
                    break;
            }

            if (_selectedButton < 1)
                _selectedButton += 12;
            else if (_selectedButton > 12)
                _selectedButton -= 12;
            _buttonDict[_selectedButton].Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

I notice a hitch when you hit a key...there's a default behavior in the form where it attempts to handle the arrow key to move to the next in the Tab Order.  Solve that and you've got it.  Sorry, but I'm out of time to work on this.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. I haven't managed to get it working yet, but i do have some questions about the code for my personal understanding. Why use the button tags when populating the dictionary? Wouldn't a List be better? Thank you

Comment: I assume you mean a list in code.  But what tie does that have to the physical button?  Using the `Tag` property on the button gives you that physical link.  In this code example, it's more forward-thinking than practical.  Suppose at some point you need the button to tell you which number it is?  Using the `Tag`, it can.